# unable to get the response in the res.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to call sql module inside the sql module and push the second level module into the first level module array so that i can get the result. 
But the i getting the null array in the output.

```
router.post('/mymsg', function(req, res, next) {
      var rootmsgid = req.body.rootmsgid;
      var request = new sql.Request()
        .input('rootmsgid', sql.Int, rootmsgid)

        .execute('sp_mymsg')
        .then(function(val) {
          var x = val.recordsets[0]
          var z = [];
          var y  = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

            var t1 = parseInt(x[i].msg_id)
            var t2 = parseInt(x[i].sender_id)
            var t3 = x[i].timestamp
            var t4 = x[i].recipient
            var t5 = x[i].subject
            var t6 = x[i].body


         var request = new sql.Request()
        .input('msgid', sql.Int, t1)

        .execute('filenamex')
        .then(function( val) {
         y =  val.recordsets[0];
         z.push({
                  "msg_id": t1,
                  "sender_id": t2,
                  "timestamp": t3,
                  "recipient": t4,
                  "subject": t5,
                  "body": t6,

                  "filename": y
                })

    console.log(z)

        })


     }
      res.json(z)

        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.json({
            msg: "Invalid Input",
            success: false
          });
          res.end();
        });
    });
```

I am trying to call sql module inside the sql module and push the second level module into the first level module array so that i can get the result. 
But the i getting the null array in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to async programming :)

Your `res.json(z)` gets executed before your for loop finishes.
That's you are getting an empty array.
Use the async module or use async/await to resolve.

Comment: or they could just continue the `Promise` chain and add another `.then` without `async/await` wrapper